# Is it possible in Maven to use an external file to define dependency versions?

Tags: maven-3

Specifically, is it possible to read a properties file, then use the properties defined in it
to specify the dependency versions, for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-logging.version}</version> <!--should come from an external file -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a parent POM or the `import` scope?

Comment: I want to keep dependency versions in sync between a project built with maven and another one which is built with something else (changing that is not an option) and specifies its dependency versions via a properties file.

Comment: It's theoretically possible (I've seen references but haven't set anything except from the command line myself), but this sounds like a great case for Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You can go the other way a round and let maven write the property file which contains the values for the dependenciy via [Properties Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/write-project-properties-mojo.html).

You can define a property like this in you pom file:

```xml
  <properties>
    <commons-logging.version>2.3</commons-logging.vesion>
  </properties>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-logging.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

and read the file in your legacy build.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is not feasible in the current setup. The properties file is what most everyone has access to, and is familiar with. The project built by maven is developed by very few people in a separate repository. It would be not reasonable to make this repository the origin of the version information.